# Google Plus API slow response times for large request due to max results of 20.

Tags: rest, parallel-processing, google-api, google-plus

I'm trying to grab 200 Google Plus Activities posts for a dashboard I'm creating. But there is a max limit of 20 posts per request, and a next page token is given. Because I have to use the nextpagetoken from the previous response to make the next request, I'm not sure how I can make the requests in parallel. It takes about 1 second to get a response, so for 10 requests this is taking around 10 seconds, which is a very long time for a search result of a dashboard to load.

Do anybody have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The Max results per page limit for [activities.search](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/activities/search)  is  20 you can't increase that.

You can not run these requests in parallel as there is no way for you to calculate the next page token that is created for you by Google.  Even if there was you would end up hitting the flood protection quota.

1 second to get a response isnt bad IMO for a free api that you are not paying for.   You need to work with in the limits that Google has set for the API.   Even if you want to go faster you can't if Google won't allow it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. 

I am using searching activities posts, which is from here: https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/activities/search. The limit is 20 there, what you stated is searching for posts from a specific user.

Second, Google can handle 10 requests per second and more. So that is also wrong. 

Third, I am building a professional dashboard for users, so I'll be the judge of if 10 second wait time for my users for a single search result just to request the data without preprocessing is slow or fast.

Thanks.

Comment: yes Google can handle it but they have it throttle they are not going to let you go any faster.   You are limited to what Google will allow you to do like the rest of use developers working on professional applications with Google free services.